# Does anyone know is it possible to change site collection user id?

Tags: sharepoint-server

Hi SharePoint experts!

Does anyone know is it possible to change site collection user id or create a new one with specific ID. (SPUser.UserId) I know the property is exposed only with getter.

If you wonder why. 
We have Document Set collection with about 50K sets. A user id is associated with an access function, for some reason a new user id was created and old deleted. Now significant part of document sets are not accessible as user id is changed. The solution could be to change user ID back to old one (available, not assigned) or much more efforts to update all document sets with new user id.

Has anyone delt with this?

Victor

Comment: what yo mean by user ID? is it the ID assigned to a user? did the user get deleted and recreated?

Comment: Not sure how did it happen, we've been working on profile synchronization and access rights. It might been deleted and re-created. Work haven't been completed, hopefully it won't happen again if we update document collection. Yes it's site user id
#ID;<User AD name>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is possible.  Well - in a supported fashion.  There may be some temporary ways around that - such as manipulating the userinfo table in a site collection, but you would need to keep that from being synced with the user profile service. It may be possible to directly edit the user profile database and force a sync to universally update the ID - but that would be unsupported and is just a wild guess from me. If this user was deleted and recreated in AD with a new SID, you have another layer of complexity involved with correcting it.

You are better off scripting out a solution to update the document sets.

Comment: Thank you Jesus for reply and suggestions.
I was not planning on going with unsupported route, was wondering if MS could assist, may be someone done it.
I would go with your scripting suggestion.